# Trouble with accessing flask-socketio session

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, eventlet, flask-socketio

When I run my local application with `flask-socketio` I can access **session** using `from flask import session`, but when I run it with *gunicorn* on server (`gunicorn --worker-class eventlet -w 1 app:app`) it return me `session.keys()` as **Array[0]**.

How could I fix it to establish this local-proxy with session on server?

Thanks

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, request
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)


@app.before_request
def before_request():
    session['key_1'] = 'Hello,'
    session['key_2'] = 'World'


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('connect', namespace='/')
def socket_connect():
    session_keys = session.keys()
    emit('connect response', {
        'session_keys': session_keys
    })


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/')
def socket_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected', request.sid)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: You haven't included the template, but I'm not sure that will actually change anything. I'm trying your code here with a made up template and I do see the session keys, with or without gunicorn. Do you have any other components in your set up that you did not mention?

Comment: Yea, my bad. Tested the simple one and it worked well, but in my complicated project it uses redis, mongodb components, maybe it could the reason why it isnt showing the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.
Session was dissapearing and could not be shared to socketio, because I added redirect page rules on cloudflare for my domain.
When I changed Forwarding type of all rules to 302 - Temporary everything worked well.